# Switch Membership Profile to other Profile without password?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an application where every user stores his settings with the AspNetSqlProfileProvider in the aspnet_Profiles table. Now I want to give the administrator the possibility to switch to another user to see his settings. But I don't know the windows password of the other user (and I don't want to know it) so I'm not able to use the windows impersonate function, right?

So is there any possibility to switch to another user profile without password?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Windows Authentification or Form Authentification ?

Comment: Windows Authentication (sorry, forgot it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to switch from user profile without password, you have to implement your own membership provider and your own loginpage for the super user. In the custom membership provider you do not authenticate the login on username and password, but on the username and superuser credentials. If the superuser is logged on he can access the 'switch' page.

[Writing a Custom Membership Provider for the Login Control in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm)

Comment: Isn't this for form authentication only?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm almost sure it is not possible with windows authentication.